# Remove dynamically appended <TR> from jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I append the `<tr>` to `<tbody>`

```
for (var i = 0 ;i < 12 ;i++){
  $(`<tr><td>test</td></tr>`).appendTo('#songsTbody');
}
```

to this html.

```
<tbody id="songsTbody">
</tbody>
```

Now I want to remove() only appended `<tr>` but

```
$('#songsTbody').remove();
```

it remove `<tbody>` itself.

How can I remove only `<tr>`??

Comment: Did you try `$('#songsTbody > tr').remove();` ?

Comment: You can also use [`$('#songsTbody').empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) to remove all child elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a selector into the `.remove()` call so if there are no other s and you want to remove them all, you could do `$('#songsTbody').remove('tr')` or even just `$('#songsTbody tr').remove()`.

If you need to just remove the last one that was added, you could try `$('#songsTbody tr:last-child').remove()` or `$('#songsTbody').remove('tr:last-child')`

Comment: `$('#songsTbody').remove('tr')` perfectly hits my case. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can recognize appended `<TR>` adding a data attribute or a class.

```
for (var i = 0 ;i < 12 ;i++){
  $(`<tr class="appended"><td>test</td></tr>`).appendTo('#songsTbody');
}
```

and after you can easily remove just new TR with

```
$('#songsTbody').remove('tr.appended')
```

Comment: It also a nice hint but, in this case remove('tr') is more simple. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Save it in a variable(s).

```js
var arr = []
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  var elem = $(`<tr><td>test</td></tr>`);
  elem.appendTo('#songsTbody');
  arr.push(elem);
}

// remove:
arr.forEach((elem) => elem.remove());
```

Comment: Thank you it is basically straight idea and it can work for many cases.